# Who's liable for copyright infringement when hiring a design company?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, international

If company A pays company B to create an ad/logo/video/etc. and then uses it, what happens if company B used copyrighted material without obtaining the necessary permissions, unbeknown to company A? Is company A liable for that?

I assume they wouldn't be able to use the material after being informed of the infringement and presented proof of that. I'm asking about if they ***don't*** know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, company A is liable for that; ignorance is not a defence.

For this reason, a prudent company A would put an indemnification clause in their contract with company B so that if A is sues then company B pays. This is, of course, completely useless if company B is out of business at the time of the suit.

Comment: Actually, ignorance usually _is_ a defence to criminal proceedings for copyright infringement (in places which have them). However, civil liability remains, which is usually the main concern.

Comment: @sleske the question is about liability which is usually about civil actions

Comment: Well, I'm neither a native speaker nor a lawyer, but as far as I understand "liable"/"liability" is also used to include criminal matters (e.g, Google has almost 2 mio. hits for "criminal liability"). I just wanted to mention it for completeness' sake.

Comment: Just to add as a designer – Prudent design company B will put a clause in the contract making it clear they don't take any liability unless negligence can be proved. And they'll have insurance anyway; don't work with a design agency which doesn't have professional indemnity insurance. Company A should also have their own insurance.